# ADO Execution - compile error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel, ado, jet

I have the following ado connection from excel to access but it does not work, am getting the error above. Any ideas?

```
Sub ADO_to_access()

Dim database As New ADODB.Connection  // ERROR HERE
Dim connectionstring As String
Dim NewSet As Recordset
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
Set objaccess = Nothing

connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\VBA - CW - Database.mdb;"

database.Open connectionstring

' ************* MEN
Set NewSet = New ADODB.Recordset
NewSet.Open "Mens_Dept_Data", database, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

x = 6
Do While Len(Range("P" & x).Formula) > 0
With NewSet
.AddNew

.Fields("Irina").Value = CurrentSheet.Range("P" & x).Value
.Fields("Thomas").Value = CurrentSheet.Range("Q" & x).Value
.Fields("Jackie").Value = CurrentSheet.Range("R" & x).Value

.Update
End With
x = x + 1
Loop

NewSet.Close
database.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: by the way, there is a bug in the code formatting on SO. To avoid it, "close" the comment with a ' at then end of your comments  :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you reference the adodb library ? (From VBE, select Tools, References)

Comment: Microsoft ADO ext 6.0 for DDL and Security?

Comment: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x There are often many of them. Choose the one you need, if you don't know, select the most recent.

Comment: mmmm... now i get "provider cannot be found, might not be properly installed" in line `database.Open connectionstring`

Comment: I guess error line should read "Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection", and then you define your db "Set database = cn.openDatabase...". But I never use ADO, always DAO, so I am a bit stuck here, sorry.

Comment: You do not use Set to open a connection string, because the object is already created with New. Make sure that you have :\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Dao\Dao360.dll, also are you using 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the problem might be in those types:

```
adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```

Try to define them as follows:

```
var adOpenForwardOnly = 0, adOpenKeyset = 1, adOpenDynamic = 2, adOpenStatic = 3; //CursorType Values
var adLockReadOnly = 1, adLockPessimistic = 2, adLockOptimistic = 3, adLockBatchOptimistic = 4; //LockTypeEnum Values
var adStateClosed = 0, adStateOpen = 1, adStateConnecting = 2, adStateExecuting = 4; //ObjectStateEnum Values 
var adUseServer = 2, adUseClient = 3 //CursorLocationEnum Values 
var adCmdTable = 2 //CommandTypeEnum Values
```

After Edit:

Sorry this is for the JScrip dialect, but I am sure that you can chang it to VBScript. :)